How is @Microsoft.KeyVault implemented? Is it possible to write a custom transformation like this?
There is a @Microsoft.KeyVault directive that can be used in appsettings that effectively transforms the appsetting value into a value in the referenced key vault.
How is this implemented? Would it be possible to write a custom converter?
E.g. "MySetting": "@MyClass(Val=123)" which would result in calling MyClass with 123 parameter that would then produce a new configuration value.
I did search the Internet, but I'm likely using wrong words. I cannot find neither information on the subject nor the source code for @Microsoft.KeyVault.

it looks like you can use it only in Azure see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/890662/webapp-configuration-how-to-provide-reference-to-k

No, you can't. The app settings values will be passed as environment variables. The key vault references are a nifty feature which will make the resource retrieve the variables before passing them as environment variables. Your app then has the ability to retrieve those variables and do something with them.
So it's not your code retrieving the values from the key vault, but the resource. Therefore you also can't implement any custom 'converters' yourself. You're still free to do whatever you want with the value in your code and implement custom logic there.
This can also be tested when you using the Console of your web app resource from the Azure Portal. Setup an app setting called mysecret which references a key vault secret and then call the following command from the console:
echo %mysecret%

That will print out the value of the secret rather than the reference while running outside of your web app.

Apparently, you can. There is a number of nuget packages, that hook up to the configuration just after it has been built and rewrite already existing config values if they are defined in a special format.
I went with the Steeltoe package. It lets you to write appsettings as "key": "Val${keyvault-secret-name} and will perform the substitution.
